# Make a fixed and responsive div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this design made using bootstrap there is a left side bar 100% in height. And there is a content area on the left. The left sidebar is fixed using position : fixed so it stays fixed when scrolling down. It's fine on desktop.

However when it's being viewed from mobile the the fixed sidebar goes to the  top like in any other responsive design. Fine. But the content area on the right in desktop comes on top of the sidebar not bottom to it cause the position : fixed.

How can i fix it? Keep the sidebar fixed in desktop and make it responsive on mobile?

Sorry i'm being on mobile

html

```
<div class='col-md-3' id='sidebar'>Sidebar</div>
<div class='col-md-9'>
content
</div>
```

css

```
#sidebar 
{
 height :100%;
 position : fixed;
 }
html,body
 { 
 height : 100%;
 }
```

Comment: Post some code, it's pretty hard to imagine your site

Comment: Looks like a good time to use *media queries* ?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes media queries worked thanks :) can you put that as an answer so i can mark it as correct? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion: **use *@media queries***

```
@media (max-width: 768px) { /* mobile view */
  #sidebar  {
    position: relative;
    // or any other property to achieve the desired
  }
}
```

[**MDN** CSS/Media_queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)
[**Css-Tricks** Suggested Standard Media Sizes](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Answer (score 0):

You must be using 'position: fixed;' instead if 'absolute' due to some layout issue faced in Safari or Chrome on Mac! I also faced this problem in an app. Try to search the solution on Chrome Developers forum.

Answer (score 0):

It is tough to diagnose without more to go from, however you oculd try the following:

On `#sidebar` instead of using `height: 100%;` use:

```
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
```

Comment: yes it does work but it's not fixed when scrolling, making the change and keeping position fixed makes no difference